# Mirror Gitlab to Bitbucket Cloud - Authentication problem with bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I am trying to setup mirroring so that I can push any commits I make to my local gitlab instance to my bitbucket repo. I have created an access token on my bitbucket repo but any attempt to add it to the mirroring in gitlab results in authentication errors regardless of which protocol I use

[image: Screenshot of Gitlab Mirroring Setup page]

If I hover over the respective ERROR pill as shown in the screenshot it says the following:

SSH:
"13:get remote references: create git ls-remote: exit status 128, stderr: "Host key verification failed.\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"."

HTTPS:
"13:get remote references: create git ls-remote: exit status 128, stderr: "remote: Invalid credentials\nfatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/USERNAME/xxxx-repo-name-xxxx.git/'\n"."

I am at a loss as to what the problem is, I know the credentials are correct. I have added bitbucket.org to my known-hosts and I dont know what to try next. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket SSH does not support username and password or username or token - it's all SSH keys. (This is also the case for GitHub and GitLab.)

GitLab's mirroring documentation says that they will generate a keypair for you if you select "SSH Public Key" as the authentication method for SSH. You'll need to choose that, then fetch the public key they provide, and add that new public key as an access key on the Bitbucket repo(s).

Relevant docs:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/#get-your-ssh-public-key
- https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-repository-access-keys-on-linux/#Provide-Bitbucket-Cloud-with-your-public-key

Comment: Super, this sounds like the detail I was missing. I'm AFK right now but will try this as soon as I can. Thanks for the clear, detailed and well written reply.